# How to make default ElasticSearch operation on entity with conditon( field LIKE not EQUAL )

Tags: elasticsearch, jhipster, spring-data-elasticsearch

I m new to ElasticSearch functionality , i ve a generated entity named **project** 
this project entity have ( name ,description , budget and other more fields ) 
By default when ElasticSearch is enabled **jhipster** create a search box field and looks like it executes this sql request

```
 SELECT * from Project WHERE name="fieldValue" OR description ="fieldValue" OR ....
```

Here below **search** method in my **ProjectServiceImpl**

```
@Transactional(readOnly = true)
public Page<ProjectDTO> search(String query, Pageable pageable) { 
    return projectSearchRepository.search(queryStringQuery(query), pageable)
        .map(projectMapper::toDto);
}
```

But i want to list projects with ( condition WHERE name LIKE fieldValue OR description LIKE fieldValue ...)

To be honest I m new with ElasticSearch I don't know how to work with **QueryStringQueryBuilder** , I have done a lot googling but i don't find a concrete example and any help is appreciated.

Comment: what you need to use in elasticsearch is Boolean Queries. 
You can try the _sql/translate to help you build your query https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/sql-translate.html
But I don't know anything on jhipster's implementation

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I founded a workaround just i ve to use QueryBuilder and pass query parameter between two asterisks *****

```
 public Page<ProjectDTO> search(String query, Pageable pageable) { 

       QueryBuilder queryBuilder = QueryBuilders.boolQuery()
            .should(QueryBuilders.queryStringQuery("*"+query+"*")
             .lenient(true)
                .field("name")
                .field("description")); 

        return projectSearchRepository.search(queryBuilder, pageable)
            .map(projectMapper::toDto);
}
```